# Show validation messages on partial views in asp.net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following model in order to show validations on multiselect list

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AccountManagementUI.Models
{
    public class NewMembersAddViewModel
    {
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> membersList { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please select atlast 1 employee")]
        public List<Guid> selectedMembersId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller post method is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetNewMembers(NewMembersAddViewModel groupMemberData)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AddMembersToGroup addMembersToGroup = new AddMembersToGroup();
                addMembersToGroup.GroupId = groupMemberData.GroupId;
                foreach (var memberId in groupMemberData.selectedMembersId)
                {
                    addMembersToGroup.UserIds.Add(memberId.ToString());
                }
                _gateway.AddMembersToGroup(addMembersToGroup);
                return RedirectToAction("GroupMembers", "Group", new { groupId = groupMemberData.GroupId });
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("_GetNewMembers", groupMemberData);
            }
            
        }
```

My view is as below:

```
@model AccountManagementUI.Models.NewMembersAddViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Active Directory Management Portal</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!-- Pagelevel Initializations Of Plugins -->
</head>
<body>
        <form class="console-panel grid-stack-item-content" asp-action="GetNewMembers" asp-controller="Group" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="GroupId" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="GroupName" />
        <div class="console-panel-body pl-0 pr-0">
            <div class="console-form-body ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Members</label>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <select asp-for="selectedMembersId" asp-items="Model.membersList" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select Members" onchange="console.log($(this).children(':selected').length)" class="search-box form-control">
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="selectedMembersId" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="console-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <a id="addMembersCancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onclick="AddNewMembersCancel()">Cancel</a>
        </div>

    </form>
    <script>
        $('.search-box').SumoSelect({ csvDispCount: 3, search: true, searchText: 'Enter here.' });
    </script>
    <script>
        function AddNewMembersCancel() {
            $('#addNewMemberModal').modal('hide');
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have given validations of selecting at least one member but when I click submit button without selecting member then it redirects to new page and shows the message there. I want to show the message on the same partial view when clicked submit?

Comment: Just add 'required' attribute to your select markup.

Comment: Hi, @Ajinkya G, please let us know if you have updated information on this issue.

Comment: I solved the issue by doing something else than this.

Comment: @Ajinkya G, your question might be relevant to others in the future, if possible, please finish the issue and share your solution with others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your validation scripts **jquery.validate.min.js** and **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js**.

[Client-side validation](http://jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js)

The partial view _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml from shared folder can be added to your view:

```
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `<form>` element with a `submit` button which by default will cause you page to reload on `submit`.

In order to show the error on the same page when you click submit, you need to prevent the default behavior of the form.

First, you will need some kind of `id` on your `form` element. Let's say the `id` is `new-members-form`.

```html
<form id="new-members-form" class="console-panel grid-stack-item-content" asp-action="GetNewMembers" asp-controller="Group" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Then, you need to select the form and tell it to stop executing the default behavior on form submit.

With JQuery:

```js
$("new-members-form").on("submit", (event) => { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Or plain JS:

```js
document.getElementById("new-members-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When first time to view or failed to add, remember to set the `memberList`.

> Codes of controller:

```
     //Members to SelectListItem
    public IList<SelectListItem> GetMembers()
    {
        var members = new List<Member>
        {
            new Member {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Ada"},
            new Member {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Brain"},
            new Member {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Cater"},
        };

        var memberListItem = members
       .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() })
       .ToList();

        return memberListItem;
    }


    [Route("/members")]
    public IActionResult _GetNewMembers()
    {
        var model = new NewMembersAddViewModel { 
                           membersList = GetMembers() 
                    };

        return View(model);
    }

    
    [Route("/api/Group/GetNewMembers")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetNewMembers(NewMembersAddViewModel groupMemberData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Success                
            return RedirectToAction("GroupMembers", "Group", new { groupId = groupMemberData.GroupId });

        }
        else
        {
            //when failed, set the memberList again.
            groupMemberData.membersList = GetMembers(); 

            return PartialView("_GetNewMembers", groupMemberData);
        }

    }
```

Codes of view are same as you.

Comment: For me, I have opened partial view in Popup I am getting the error but as it is post method it is directing to new page and showing the error

Comment: @Ajinkya G , you could use jQuery to send ajax and validate modal actions. I answered in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371567/how-to-validate-in-modal/63377914#63377914). Feel free to ask if you have any questions with that.